# Mulitprocessing and rpy2 (with ape)

Tags: python, r, multiprocessing, rpy2, ape-phylo

I ran into this today and can't figure out why.  I have several functions chained together that perform some time consuming operations as part of a larger pipeline.  I've included these here, pared down to a test example, as best as I could.  The issue is that when I call a function directly, I get the expected output (e.g., 5 different trees).  However, when I call the same function in a multiprocessing pool with apply_async (or apply, doesn't matter), I get 5 trees, but they are all the same.

I've documented this in an IPython notebook, which can be viewed here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/cfriedline/0e275d528ff1a8d674c6

In cell 91, I create 5 trees (each with 10 tips), and return two lists.  The first containing the non-multiprocessing trees, and the second from apply_async.

In cell 92, you can see the results of creating trees without multiprocessing, and in 93, with multiprocessing.

What I expect is that there would be a total of 10 different trees between the two tests, but instead all of the multiprocessing trees are identical.  Makes little sense to me.

Relevant versions of things:

- Linux 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit)
- IPython 2.0.0
- Rpy2 2.3.9

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2):

I solved this one, with a point in the right direction from @mgilson.  In fact, it was a random number problem, just not in python - in R (sigh).  The state of R is copied when the Pool is created, meaning so is its random seed.  To fix, just a little rpy2 as below calling R's set.seed function (with some process specific stuff for good measure):

```
def create_tree(num_tips, type):
    """
    creates the taxa tree in R
    @param num_tips: number of taxa to create
    @param type: type for naming (e.g., 'taxa')
    @return: a dendropy Tree
    @rtype: dendropy.Tree
    """
    r = rpy2.robjects.r
    set_seed = r('set.seed')
    set_seed(int((time.time()+os.getpid()*1000)))
    rpy2.robjects.globalenv['numtips'] = num_tips
    rpy2.robjects.globalenv['treetype'] = type
    name = _get_random_string(20)
    if type == "T":
        r("%s = rtree(numtips, rooted=T, tip.label=paste(treetype, seq(1:(numtips)), sep=''))" % name)
    else:
        r("%s = rtree(numtips, rooted=F, tip.label=paste(treetype, seq(1:(numtips)), sep=''))" % name)
    tree = r[name]
    return ape_to_dendropy(tree)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% familiar with these libraries, however, on Linux, (IIRC) `multiprocessing` uses `os.fork`.  This means that the state of the random module (which you're using) will also be forked and that each of your processes will generate *the same sequence of random numbers* resulting in a not-so-random `_get_random_string` function.

If I'm right, and you make the pool smaller than the number of trees that you want, you should see that you get groups of N identical trees (where N is the number of pools).

I think that probably the ideal solution is to [re-seed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) the random number generator inside of each of the processes.  It's unlikely that they'll run at *exactly* the same time, so you should get differing results.

Comment: That's a good call - I'll check that.  Additionally, I set it up to use IPython.parallel, too (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/cfriedline/57c9f35b31225ced7931).  No issues like with multiprocessing, so it's another option, I guess.  Just more setup.

Comment: I even tried with scipy.random.choice coupled with scipy.random.seed, same problem.  Hmmph.

Comment: Well, I'm getting closer, but I'm still not getting the right stuff back from my code, though the testing works.  test: http://pastie.org/9256603#, new notebook with updated code: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/cfriedline/0095ad55d645a7202cc6